# Pgbouncer how to test usefullness using query

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer, high-load

I've got Postgres 13 version and PG-bouncer.
How can I using connection and query to database test usefulness
of pgbouncer?
I mean start query which generate connections or other and
at the end of test we see that time of query is lower, or
workload on database without bouncer is higher?

Comment: use PGBENCH tool https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html

Comment: pgbouncer can server many different purposes and has many different configurations.  How to demonstrate its efficacy depends on why you are using it and how you have it configured.